# Specify cordapps folder when running a corda node

Tags: corda

The `java -jar corda.jar` command picks up cordapps from `$basedir/cordapps` by default. Is there an option to specify an alternatively cordapps directory? This may be useful when multiple nodes are sharing the same set of cordapps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible to override only cordapp path. You can override the workspace directory and other fields in the node.conf ([documentation](https://docs.r3.com/en/platform/corda/4.6/open-source/corda-configuration-file.html)).

An option could be to mount a folder in each node from a shared filesystem (e.g. EFS on AWS) where you store the cordapps.